# SQL Many to one with Boolean

Tags: sql

I am trying to set up a SQL Statement that returns a 1 when one item is true.

```
ID  |  ID2  | color | is blue present
---------------------------------------
1   |  12   | blue  | 1
1   |  12   | red   | 1 
1   |  13   | red   | 0
```

So using the above table when I have combined key of `ID` and `ID2` having the `color` blue no matter what other color this same key combination  contains it should always have `is blue present` as 1.

I am thankful for any help.

Comment: I'd start by getting a list of ID/ID2 keys that have a record with the color blue.  Then join to this table and if the key is in the blue table, set the flag to 1 and if not to 0.

Comment: use `CASE WHEN`. This should get you the result you need.

Comment: You didn't specify your RDBMS; If [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)... If [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm).

Comment: If you are on some modern version of DBMS, use windowing aggregate, MS SQL 2012+ for example: `select ID,ID2,color,
    [is blue present] = max(case color when 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by ID,ID2)`

Comment: Going through your comments I was able to use what was here to solve my issue.  Thank you very much.  I am not SQL Developer normally and was asked to do this to help out.  Again thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You could left-join the query on a query that retrieves only blue values:

```
SELECT    a.id, a.id2, a.color, 
          CASE WHEN b.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_blue_present
FROM      mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b ON a.id = b.id AND a.id2 = b.id2 AND b.color = 'blue'
```